# net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not create the DataSource

Tags: kotlin, liquibase, corda, discord

I'm trying to develop a CorDapp using the example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Basic). I've added two modules into my project, one for contracts and the other one for flows. I've added test cases for my contract and it works fine, but test cases for flow fail on setup stage. Here's the code of my test class

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 class SharedInformationFlowTests {
   private lateinit var network: MockNetwork
   private lateinit var a: StartedMockNode
   private val proposal = LedgerUpdateProposal.testProposal()

@BeforeAll
fun setup() {
    val params = MockNetworkParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
            TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.something.contract")
    ))

    network = MockNetwork(params) //fails here
    a = network.createPartyNode()
    network.runNetwork()
}

@AfterAll
fun tearDown() {
    network.stopNodes()
}
```

And here are the error messages I get:

```
[WARN] 13:42:52,620 [main] spi.SqlExceptionHelper. - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda, databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
[ERROR] 13:42:52,620 [main] spi.SqlExceptionHelper. - Connection is closed {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda, databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}


net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not create the 
DataSource: Migration failed for change set migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda:
 Reason: net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.HibernateConfigException: Could not create Hibernate configuration: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

I think there's something wrong with the liquibase. I've tried adding changelog file to my `resources/migration` directory as [advised here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.2/database-management.html), but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Please help.

**UPDATE** Added schema

```
/**
 * The family of com.sentinel.schemas for SharingInformationState.
 */
object SharingInformationSchema

/**
 * An SharingInformationState schema.
 */
object SharingInformationSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
    schemaFamily = SharingInformationSchema.javaClass,
    version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentSharingInformation::class.java)) {
override val migrationResource: String? = "sharing-information-schema-v1.changelog-master.xml"

@Entity
@Table(name = "persistent_sharing_information")
class PersistentSharingInformation(
        @Column(name = "owner_id")
        var dataOwnerId: Long,

        @Column(name = "buyer_id")
        var dataBuyerId: Long,

        @Column(name = "start_date")
        val startDate: String,

        @Column(name = "end_date")
        val endDate: String,

        @Column(name = "shared_fields")
        val sharedFieldsIds: String,

        @Column(name = "agreement_status")
        val agreementStatus: String,

        @Column(name = "contract_type")
        val contractType: String,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linearId: UUID
) : PersistentState() {

    // Default constructor required by hibernate.
    constructor() : this(0L,  0L,
            "", "", "[]", "", "", UUID.randomUUID())
}
```

}

```
 @BelongsToContract(com.package.contract.SharingInformationContract::class)
 class SharingInformationState(val ourParty: Party,
                          val proposal: LedgerUpdateProposal,
                          override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()) : LinearState, QueryableState {

override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(ourParty)

override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
    return when (schema) {
        SharingInformationSchemaV1 -> SharingInformationSchemaV1.PersistentSharingInformation(
                proposal.ownerId,
                proposal.buyerId,
                proposal.startDate,
                proposal.endDate,
                proposal.sharedFieldsIds.toString(),
                proposal.agreementStatus.name,
                proposal.contractType.name,
                linearId.id
        )
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
    }
}

override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(SharingInformationSchemaV1)

}

  @CordaSerializable
  enum class AgreementStatus { APPROVED, REJECTED }
  @CordaSerializable
  enum class ContractType { CORPORATE, CONSUMER, MARKETING, BINDING }
```

Comment: Judging by the annotations, you are using `JUnit 5` which I also prefer and have used before without any problems; but I know that R3 engineers always use `JUnit 4` and that's what Corda supports. It's worth trying `JUnit 4` and see if the error goes away.  
Also, what does `LedgerUpdateProposal.testProposal()` do? I've never seen this line before in any test; try to comment it out before changing JUnit version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. LedgerUpdateProposal is my State class. Tried to switch to JUnit 4 - didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your repository with me? Either drop a link here, or send it on Corda’s Slack (cordaledger.slack.com).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is forbidden in my company.

Comment: No, problem; I assume that your state has a custom schema, maybe you didn’t write it correctly and that’s causing Liquibase to fail? Also make sure that you’re using the recommended Oracle JDK 8 version.

Comment: I've added the schema to the question.

Comment: I'm comparing your custom schema object with the code [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/schema/IOUSchema.kt), only difference is you adding `migrationResource`; not sure what's that for, maybe try commenting it out? Also can you update your question with the code of your state which defines `generateMappedObject()` and `supportedSchemas()` functions?

Comment: migrationResource is not the reason. I've added it in hope that it solves the issue, but it didn't. But, I've added the state class as well.

Comment: hmm, all looks good to me :-/ maybe raise an issue on Corda's repository and reference this question? Corda's Slack channel is also a good place, you can post a link to this question there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Let's see where it gets us. https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6386